# It's possible that I used to be like that

Tags: phrases

Situation: you just watched a video of a baby **crying** incessantly, which you thought that *you might be like the baby* when you were at that age (now you are an adult). You express this as:

> "It's possible that I used to be like that."

Is the phrase correct in relation to what I'm really trying to say?

Comment: Sounds fine to me, although I can't imagine you saying it as anything other than a question addressed to your parents, *"Was I ever like that?"*  or *"I was never like that, was I?"*

Comment: It's technically OK, but you would need to tell us who you are saying it to, and in what context, to determine if it would be appropriate. *possible* may not be the right word, since most all of us were like that as babies, at some point.